# 'Settings' object has no attribute 'RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, recaptcha

I got this Error when user want to register:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/register/'

'Settings' object has no attribute 'RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8009/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Settings' object has no attribute 'RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'

Exception Location: /home/ali/bestoon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __getattr__, line 57

Python Executable:  /home/ali/bestoon/.venv/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/ali/bestoon/bestoon',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ali/bestoon/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: How does your `settings.py` look?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid
part 2 of setting.py:


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web',
]

Comment: That's enough =) Make sure that's not your production key!

Comment: The problem there is you are missing the `Y` at the end of `_KEY`

Comment: you should delete those comments =)

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid
fixed

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid
no !
PMMailMissingValueException at /accounts/register/

'Cannot send an e-mail without a Postmark API Key'

how to handle this?

Comment: That is a different problem :) make sure you have your api key set.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid  
yeah,how i can get my API Key ?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid  
yeah,how i can get my API Key ?

Comment: You need to do that with your account. Have a read over their docs.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid which account?

Comment: Postmark. It says it in your exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `Y` from `RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KE` in your settings.